# Why can't my two docker containers communicate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, docker, flask

I have two docker containers running Flask, just a simple backend/frontend example bit I was running through to learn docker and flask.

My frontend is:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import requests
import simplejson
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    uri = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/tasks"
    try:
        uResponse = requests.get(uri)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return "Connection Error"

    Jresponse = uResponse.text
    data = json.loads(Jresponse)
    fullString = ""

    title = data['tasks'][0]['title']
    description = data['tasks'][0]['description']

    fullString += title
    fullString += "<br/>"
    fullString += description

    return fullString


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host="0.0.0.0", port=2000)
```

This works fine when I run it locally, and it also works when I run it in my docker.  I'm able to go to the frontend at `localhost:2000` and I see valid data.

My backend code is:

```
from flask import Flask,request, jsonify, make_response
from flask import abort
import csv
import json
import flask

app = Flask(__name__)

tasks = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': u'example title 1',
        'description': u'example description 1', 
        'done': False
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': u'example title 2',
        'description': u'example description 2', 
        'done': False
    }
]

@app.route('/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify({'tasks': tasks})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

If I run both of these without docker, and I go to the frontend at `localhost:2000` I get what I expect, the 0th entry of tasks description and title.

When I run these in docker, everything seems to work, but I get the `Connection Error` from the frontend.  So, the `requests.get(uri)` seems to not be working once dockerized.

Here's my docker files

**For Backend**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER me
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev build-essential
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["backend.py"]
```

**For Frontend**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER me
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev build-essential
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV FLASK_APP=/app/frontend.py
ENV FLASK_ENV=development
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["frontend.py"]
```

So, it appears they both work individually, but can't communicate.  Why is that?  As if it isn't obvious, I'm new to docker.

---

**EDIT1**

Command for frontend:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 2000:2000 frontend
```

Command for backend:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 backend
```

**EDIT2**

I moved this to docker compose, and have the same issue it appears.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build: 
      context: backend/
      dockerfile: compose/lib/backend/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  frontend:
    build:
      context: lib/frontend/
      dockerfile: compose/lib/frontend/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "2000:2000"
```

No changes to Docker files.  According to the docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) it is correct that I don't need specific networking, and there is a default network created.  However, this still works fine under just flask, but I can't get them to attach using docker or docker-compose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you share the `docker run` command you're using?

Are you exposing the ports with the `-p` flag?

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 ...
```

**[Update]**: Depending on your docker install and config, you may not be able to use that IP. Docker considers the `127.0.0.1` IP to mean "this container," not "this machine."

A [bridged network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) may address this, but I'd recommend using `docker-compose` instead (details below).

If, for the purposes of this experiment, you are planning on running these two containers at the same time on the same machine *always*, you might want to look into [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), which lets you run multiple containers from the same master command, and gives you nice bonus features like creating a virtual network for the two to connect to each other on, without external networks being able to access them. e.g. your data server can be visible *only* to your other flask container, but *that* one can be publicly exposed on your host machine's network interface.

In the case of docker-compose, you can use the following (untested) docker-compose.yml as a start:

```
version: 3
services:
    backend:
        build: path/to/dockerfile
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
    frontend:
        build: path/to/dockerfile
        ports:
            - 2000:2000
```

Comment: I added it to the original question, but the commands were `sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 backend` and `sudo docker run -d -p 2000:2000 frontend`

Comment: Also, my end goal for doing this was actually to learn docker compose.  So, thanks, that may solve the issues.  But since I didn't know docker well I thought I'd get this running first and understand why it was working (or in this case not working) before I moved on to compose.

Comment: Just updated the answer accordingly — the issue is that 127.0.0.1 doesn't map to your host machine; it maps to the container the code is currently running in.

Comment: also added a starting-point docker-compose file to get you started :)

Comment: You don't need `links:` or any other special networking setup.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes what you get out-of-the-box, and you can communicate between containers in the same `docker-compose.yml` file using their service names as host names without any `links:`, `networks:`, `container_name:`, or other manual settings.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks! Guess i'm old-school; never stopped adding that to my yamls. Updated accordingly!

Comment: There's got to be something else wrong here.  I can't seem to get this working with docker-compose either.  It is building correctly, but they can't seem to attach to reach each other.  Works fine with just flask, but I'm definitely doing something wrong with docker.

Comment: Having said that, I'm super impressed with docker-compose so far.  Tons of extra functionality.

Comment: Got it, everything was correct, but I was making changes and didn't know `docker-compose up` didn't rebuild.  Adding the internal address in the frontend worked.  So in the frontend instead of trying to get data from `127.0.0.1:5000/tasks`, I just change it to `backend:5000/tasks` and it's perfect.  Thanks for the help!